# How can I call getColumnMeta() on cake statement

Tags: database, pdo, orm, cakephp-3.0

I want to get the **metadata** of the result-set by running something like this:

```
$stmt = $connection->execute($some_query);
return $stmt->getColumnMeta(0);
```

Because the `getColumnMeta` function is marked as **[EXPERIMENTAL](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php)** it seems that cake developers didn't activate it.

but I want to run this function on my project, how can I convert the cake statement to PdoStatement to run this function.

Comment: Whenever questions involve database related stuff, please mention the DMBS that you are using and tag your question accordingly - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe there's a simpler way but I managed to get the PDOStatement this way

```
$connection = \Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager::get('default');
$stmt = $connection->execute($some_query);
$stmt->getInnerStatement()->getInnerStatement()->getColumnMeta(0);
```

Or if you already have a Statement

```
$stmt->getInnerStatement()->getColumnMeta(0);
```

I found this solution by trial and errors looking at the API documentation. Maybe someone will give a better explanation.

Comment: Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::getInnerStatement()

Comment: so try $stmt->getInnerStatement()->getColumnMeta(0);

Comment: where does your $connection variable comes from?